# How to move an edge in edit mode without moving the meshes it connects to? Or apply a fillet?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, dupli-groups

[image]

Hi all! I want to fill in this corner with a curved fillet, but it is not as simple as clicking a fillet option on an edge in CAD. So my approach is to connect the two vertices in the image with a curved path, and use the fill faces to fill in the area. However, I can only connect the two vertices with a straight edge apparently, and to turn it into a curve I have to subdiv it into make other segments and manually move them. That's fine, but the problem is that every edge movement will move the overall meshes it connects to, but I want the meshes to stay fixed and only shape the curve. Is there a way to do so?

Furthermore, is there a way to copy the whole curved path segment post-modifying and paste it at the exact location below? Or even mirror it?

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! You can edit the vertices in vert mode; and in terms of duplication just create the face and duplicate the face directly for convenience.